# One site with many web forms projects

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I have a very big site (web application) with multiples modules.
It's in a big WebForms project.
I have to split this big project in multiples small projects. One per module.

I have to do this without having to create multiples applicarions in IIS?
How?

Tks,

Patrick Coelho - Brazil

Comment: if not create multiple application on iis, then how do you have multiple small projects that run undependable ?

Answer (score 0):

Each project will have an application entry in IIS. Create your top-level solution and add each project using the "Existing Project -> Add" menu option in Solution Explorer in VS. This is the only way to do this that I know of...

I can't see why multiple applications in IIS would be an issue.

Comment: The modules have to share the same login session.

Comment: You can customize the membership site-wide on a custom library project for this. Doable :)

Comment: The modules have to share the same login session and the web application will have a lot of modules. Approximately 80 modules.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "modules" have to share the same "session". If these are code modules whose functionality contribute to my session when I login (maybe simultaneously with others), this should not be a problem. Build it up incrementally and test it as you go...

Comment: Maintaining a project with many webforms is very difficult.
My goal is to put each part of the application on a different project, as is done in Windows Forms.
But I do not know how many webforms projects are part of the same application.

Comment: Not difficult as you might think. I have one with 22 projects in it - not a problem aside from slight lag in compile time.